# Letters as Words

Tags: letter-writing, ligature

When two letters or glyphs are joined into one glyph as a ligature, is this glyph considered two letters or one, as letters on their own are considered words as D and S, when two letters are joined as one glyph, does this glyph have a name as dee and ess and is it considered a word?

[image][image]

Comment: I really can't see how this is a question for English Language & Usage. Many or most of these ligatures aren't even seen in English. If there were a typography stack exchange you could ask there, but until then this question is so narrow in scope that it falls outside of our purview here.

Comment: Can you fix your sentence? It starts off meaningfully, but after the 2nd comma things get weird. How many questions are in this? Can you split up that run-on sentence?

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question. It's called a ligature.

Comment: Agreed. Seems that a thing is not a word. :-)  See also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_words_that_may_be_spelled_with_a_ligature

Comment: Welcome to our site. Note that you're responding to a low-quality question (which is why it's now on hold), and the system has flagged your own post for deletion as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. You can [edit] your answer to add more information, but as the Help Centre's guidance on [answer] says, "Not all questions can or should be answered here", so this question may not be worth the extra effort. :-)